# Efficient way to retrieve offset value for a given date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to calculate offset based on the Region and Day light saving, I have to do this for five date fields, hence am joining with the offset table five times now using LEFT JOIN, will it be better in terms of performance, if I create a Function and provide the date fields as parameter?

**Code Sample:**

```
SELECT 
    ModifiedDate            =   DATEADD (hh,ISNULL(DateModified.DateDateOffsetNumber, 0),T.ModifiedDate)        
    ,CreatedDate            =   DATEADD (hh,ISNULL(DateCreated.DateDateOffsetNumber, 0),T.CreatedDate)      
    ,ReceivedDateTime       =   DATEADD (hh,ISNULL(DateReceived.DateDateOffsetNumber, 0),T.ReceivedDateTime)
    ,ResolvedDate           =   DATEADD (hh,ISNULL(DateResolved.DateDateOffsetNumber, 0),T.ResolvedDate)
    ,ReactivatedDateTime    =   DATEADD (hh,ISNULL(DateReactivated.DateDateOffsetNumber, 0),T.ReactivatedDateTime)
FROM TableA T
LEFT OUTER JOIN DateOffset DateModified ON T.ModifiedDate BETWEEN DateModified.DateStartDate AND DateModified.DateEndDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN DateOffset DateCreated ON T.CreatedDate BETWEEN DateCreated.DateStartDate AND DateCreated.DateEndDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN DateOffset DateReceived ON T.ReceivedDateTime BETWEEN DateReceived.DateStartDate AND DateReceived.DateEndDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN DateOffset DateResolved ON T.ResolvedDate BETWEEN DateResolved.DateStartDate AND DateResolved.DateEndDate
LEFT OUTER JOIN DateOffset DateReactivated ON T.ReactivatedDateTime BETWEEN DateReactivated.DateStartDate AND DateReactivated.DateEndDate
```

Comment: This query doesn't make any sense. You reference DateReceived but you don't have that table or alias in here. You have the alias DateResolved in here twice which won't work. Regardless, a function is going to have the opposite effect.

Comment: I have provided proper alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will create a scalar function, the performance will be worse.

If you create an inline function, you should get a similar performance, with some (arguable) advantages in readability and maintainability:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAdjustedDate(@InputDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT DATEADD(hh,ISNULL((
    SELECT DateDateOffsetNumber
    FROM DateOffset
    WHERE @InputDate BETWEEN DateStartDate AND DateEndDate
),0),@InputDate) AS AdjustedDate

GO
SELECT 
    ModifiedDate         = (SELECT AdjustedDate FROM dbo.GetAdjustedDate(T.ModifiedDate))
    ,CreatedDate         = (SELECT AdjustedDate FROM dbo.GetAdjustedDate(T.CreatedDate))
    ,ReceivedDateTime    = (SELECT AdjustedDate FROM dbo.GetAdjustedDate(T.ReceivedDateTime))
    ,ResolvedDate        = (SELECT AdjustedDate FROM dbo.GetAdjustedDate(T.ResolvedDate))
    ,ReactivatedDateTime = (SELECT AdjustedDate FROM dbo.GetAdjustedDate(T.ReactivatedDateTime))
FROM TableA T
```